# Spring Boot 3.0 redirecting requests to error page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the following SecurityFilterChain for SpringBoot 2.7.7 and Java 17.
It works fine.
When I request a page under the "*digital*" folder, I'm required to login and am then redirected to the page.

```
http
 .authorizeHttpRequests()
             .antMatchers("/", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/digital/**").hasRole("DIGITAL")
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .formLogin()
                 .loginPage("/login")
                 .permitAll()
```

I upgrade the app to SpringBoot 3.0.2.
This requires nothing more than replacing *.antMatchers* with *.requestMatchers* in the above code and replacing javax with jakarta.

However, after upgrading, whenever I try to access any page under the "*digital*" folder I am, as expected, required to login but am then redirected to my apps error page.
Authentication and authorization seem to be OK because, after getting the error page, I can retry the link and get to the page I'm after. It's just that, first up, I always get the error page.
Anyone know what's going on? Trace for clicking on the digital/edit link attached.

```
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to app.library.AppController#editRecord(Model)
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to app.library.AppController#editRecord(Model)
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to app.library.AppController#login()
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
  s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to app.library.AppController#login()
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
```

I would expect to be redirected to the digital/edit page as under 2.7.7.
I am redirected to my default error page.

Comment: This had nothing to do with Spring-boot.
I was pointing to a non-existing jquery version in my thymeleaf page.

Answer (score 0):

See comment above. This ticket is closed.